# How can i delete files from FileManager?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

[See Image as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiKF7.png)I am working on a project, in which i need to show a UICollectionview, which includes files from filemanager, in this collectionview i am displaying images as well as folders. And there is also a button which deletes the selected cells.
So how can i delete selected folder/images from document directory?

I am creating folder with this function.

```
    func createDir() {
        let manager = FileManager.default
        guard let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            return
        }
        print("url path is ==>>",url.path)
        
        let folderName = url.appendingPathComponent(folderNameTextField.text!)
        do {
            try manager.createDirectory(at: folderName, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: [:])
            print("Saved")
            listFilesFromDocumentsFolder()
//            getAllDirectoriesList()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

`And saving images with this function

```
        func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage ) {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
//        
        let fileName = "Doc-" + dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName
        )
        if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0),!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
            do {
                try data.write(to: fileURL)
                print("file saved")
            } catch {
                print("error saving file:", error)
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using this function to delete, it works but abnormally,

```
        for file in folderImageArray {
                    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: file)
                }
```

And
This function making a crash.

```
        for file in folderNameArray {
                    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: file)
                }
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'folderImageArray' come from?  Where does a guy named 'folderNameArray' come from?  Where are your files located?  You are only allowed to work with your files without user's consent if they are located in your sandbox folder.

Comment: folderImageArray is a array of URL,Which i am using to show images in UICollectionView and folderNameArray is a array of String, which i am using to show folder names in UICollectionView.

Comment: Nobody even knows where the files shown with your collection view come from.  And where is your collection view?  What is its dataset source?

Comment: CollectionView is shown on as the main page of application.

Comment: I have added image so that anybody can get the idea. I am showing all file from document directory in UICollectionView.

Comment: Ask `FileManager` if the path or the URL exists.

Comment: Can you please tell me how? I want to delete multiple path or url.

Comment: 1. Check if the file exists (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1415645-fileexists).  2. Don't use `FileManager.default` over and over.  Make a variable out of it and use that variable repeatedly.

Comment: Please describe "works but abnormally". Any errors?

Comment: I am saying "works but abnormally" just because when i use that removeItem(at: file), it deletes multiple folders together. But I want to delete only selected folders

Answer (score 1):

You should not force unwrap try block, Use do try at-least it will give you the reason why it's not working.
Also adding a little delay will work fine

```
for file in folderImageArray {
    do {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
          try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: file)
        }
    } catch {
      print("File Deletion Failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }  

}
```

Comment: It is showing error,
No exact matches in call to instance method 'asyncAfter'.

Comment: This time also it is giving error -->> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '@convention(block) () -> Void'